# Обратный метод к Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint()

Tags: c#, unity3d

В движок Unity встроен метод `ScreenToWorldPoint()`, который координаты точки на экране конвертирует в координаты соответствующей точки на карте(сцене/мире). Есть ли в Unity обратный метод, который координаты точки на карте превращает в координаты точки на экране.

У меню есть метод:

```
    public void ShowHint(Vector2 pos, string typeOfHint)
    {
        rect.localPosition = pos;//Тут, судя по всему нужный мне метод
    }
```

`rect` - это `RectTreansform` некой `Image`-подсказки, которая должна появляться в месте, где находится объект с координатами `pos`(который точно попадает в обзор камеры).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Camera.WorldToScreenPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html)

[Camera.WorldToViewportPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToViewportPoint.html)

```
static public Vector2 WorldToCanvasPosition (GameObject obj, Canvas canvas) {
    Vector2 ViewPos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(obj.transform.Position);
    ViewPos -= new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
    Vector2 CanvasSize = canvas.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta;
    return new Vector2(ViewPos.x*CanvasSize.x, ViewPos.y*CanvasSize.y);
}
```

Comment: Зачем нужен `ViewPos -= new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f)`? Разве `WorldToViewportPoint` не возвращает уже конечные координаты вьюпорта?

Comment: А нам нужны конечные координаты вьюпорта?

Comment: В вопросе ничего не сказано, так что полагаю нужны чистые координаты `world space -> viewport`.

Comment: Сказано. Про `rect - это RectTreansform некой Image`... Боюсь viewport не зайдёт, как координата.

Comment: И причем здесь `-= new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f)`?

Comment: Ну так центр (0, 0) координат `Canvas` у нас где? И где (0, 0) у viewport.

Comment: Так бы сразу и ответили, чего было тянуть? :)

Comment: Просто ради интереса... вроде ничем другим, кроме как калибровкой эта строчка не выглядит. А ты что подозревал? :)

Comment: Да я просто как-то не обратил внимания, что речь про канвас идет, думал задача получить именно координаты вьюпорта, поэтому меня эта строка и насторожила)